# How to modify and copy observablehq zoomable sunburst to a local machine and run?

Tags: d3.js, sunburst-diagram, observablehq

I want to make the zoomable sunburst from https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst using my own data (preferably using d3.csv) on my own machine. All the downloadable versions contain the require()('observablehq/flare') using the stdlibs. When copying the observablehq version (ctrl-c/-v) code I cannot get it ti run at all and it does not seem like code in atom editor.

copy all code from the page above to   - does not run
downloadable archives (eg from vizhub (https://vizhub.com/undefined/7fcc84f68758417a8a1f6076410e98ab) contains the flare.json and flare.csv but uses the stdlib observablehq versions.

```
require()('@observablehq/flare').then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    const root = partition(data);
```

Comment: Would you accept an RStudio Quarto answer? Meaning preprocessing a standard R data.frame, passing it to ojs and then exporting a standalone chart?

Answer (score 0):

Our documentation on [Downloading & Embedding](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks) is generally the way to go for using code on Observable outside of Observable: because it's a [reactive programming environment](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/how-observable-runs), copying & pasting is only likely to work in a few isolated cases.

As far as this `require` statement: that's [d3-require](https://github.com/d3/d3-require), which you can include as an open source library, though you'd call it like `require('@observablehq/flare').then(data => {`, minus the extraneous first pair of `()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What should I write to load my own data instead of the require to load a csv file (online then?)